# Entity Framework: The data reader is incompatible

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'FurnitureStoreDataModel.Companies_GetFromUsernameWithValidationToken_Result'.
>   A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in
>   the data reader with the same name.

This is the case only when there is no suitable entry in the database. Should I handle this with a try catch wrapped around the call or is there any way to prevent this from happening?

**EDIT:**

```
public Companies_GetFromUsernameWithValidationToken_Result GetFromUsernameWithValidationToken(string username)
{
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
            {
                return context.Companies_GetFromUsernameWithValidationToken(username).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return null;
}
```

The generated code by EF:

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<Companies_GetFromUsernameWithValidationToken_Result> Companies_GetFromUsernameWithValidationToken(string username)
{
            var usernameParameter = username != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("Username", username) :
                new ObjectParameter("Username", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Companies_GetFromUsernameWithValidationToken_Result>("Companies_GetFromUsernameWithValidationToken", usernameParameter);
}
```

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Companies_GetFromUsernameWithValidationToken]    
  @Username nvarchar(50)         
AS          
BEGIN    
IF(@Username IS NOT NULL)    
BEGIN    
 DECLARE @companyId uniqueidentifier = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Companies WHERE Username = @Username)  
 IF(@companyId IS NOT NULL)  
 BEGIN  
  DECLARE @validationToken uniqueidentifier = NEWID();  
  INSERT INTO ValidationTokens(Id, CompanyId) VALUES(@validationToken, @companyId)  
   SELECT Id, Name, Username, @validationToken as [ValidationToken] FROM Companies WHERE Id = @companyId   
 END  
END   
END
```

Comment: Post code too, not just an error message.

Comment: what do u use to made the call? depends of that because some entities demand have a value...

Comment: @CoryNelson done, posted it